# Integrate indefinite function :$\int {dx\over\sqrt x \sqrt {1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate indefinite $\int {dx\over \sqrt x \sqrt {1-x}}$ using substitution? I know that the answer is $2*\arcsin(\sqrt x)+c$ by substituting $u=\sqrt x$ and $2du={dx\over\sqrt x}$ but I don't understand how plugging it in will make the function $\int {2du\over\sqrt {1-u^2}}$

Comment: The $1+u^2$ in the lower portion is confusing to me.  Is that the issue you are having as well, or are you having another issue with the derivation of the formula?

Comment: It may be a little easier to use $x=u^2$ and $dx=2udu$ in order to write the integral in terms of u.

Comment: @abiessu apologies 1+u^2 was a typing error. It's 1-u^2

Comment: @user84413 Thanks. Substituting those terms is a lot easier.

Comment: @Sydney I'm glad this made it easier; I usually try this method whenever I substitute for a root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After appropriately substituting, you *do* get an integral of the form $$\int \frac {2\,du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}$$

After all, you've correctly computed $ u = \sqrt x \implies \color{blue}{\bf u^2 = x}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\color{red}{\bf 2 \,du = \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}}$. Now, just substitute, piece for piece (match up the colors, if needed), into $$\int \dfrac{\color{red}{\bf dx}}{\color{red}{\bf \sqrt x}\cdot \sqrt{1 - \color{blue}{\bf x}}}$$
[This is the form that applies here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_.E2.88.92_x2): Now you can use the substitution $u = \sin \theta$.

Recall that when $a^2 - u^2$ occurs in an integrand, you can use the substitution $u = a\sin \theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\sin^2 t$. Then $dx=2\sin t\cos t\,dt$ and $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}=\sin t\cos t$. Thus
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=\int 2\,dt=2t+C.$$
Thus our integral is $2\arcsin(\sqrt{x})+C$.

**Remark:** The "normal" thing is to complete the square. However, $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is in many ways just as nice as $\sqrt{1-u^2}$, and one can take advantage of the special form to bypass the standard completing the square.